# Android linear layout not matching its parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am creating a listview inside a scroll view, i want the listview to match its parent. the Scroll view is matching its parent and acquiring complete screen. but the linear layout inside it is not matching its parent and acquirig the whole screen, so as the list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you are not supposed to use a ListView inside a ScrollView. The ListView is already scrollable, and using these too can only cause problems. mostly if you use dynamic sizes (fixed sized elements should perform better)

Comment: thanx, i have removed the scroll view and the linear layout, its working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as njzk2 said, you can't do that. I had issues with ListViews in a scrollview

I don't use ListViews. I just use Buttons in general. They work much better.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with following no need to use **ScrollView** or **LinearLayout** list view is default provide scroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">
             <ListView
                 android:id="@+id/listView"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent">
             </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```